# Read the list of msi files from a directory and save them in the array

Tags: .net, powershell

Following is my code to read the directory for filename with .msi extention where $to=C:\bob

```
  $listOfMSIs = Get-ChildItem –Path $to -Filter "*.msi"
```

After running the above line, Variable  $listOfMSIs will have content like this

```
    Directory: C:\bob

Mode                Last  Write  Time     Length  Name                                        
----                -------------     ------       ----                                        
-a---        09/01/2014     12:18     237568      a.msi                   
-ar--        03/06/2013     17:54    3813376      b.msi                   
-ar--        29/05/2013     14:41    2326528      c.msi
```

Now what i want to do is take the contents (msi filenames from the Name Column) and store them as
an array.

Any one got any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running PowerShell v3 or later, simply do this:

```
$FileNames = (Get-ChildItem –Path $to -Filter "*.msi").Name;
```

Comment: Can you actually do like this in Powershell? What do you get - an array of String?

Comment: Yes, an array of strings. Try it yourself.

Comment: Yes that what i got and i am using Powershell V3. Thank you Trevor

Comment: @TrevorSullivan: I am getting `$null` in `$FileNames` after running the above. Oh I see now, my PS is V2, sorry.

Comment: @Neolisk If you have not define a variable called `$to`, then the example will not work for you. And yes, this requires PowerShell version 3.0 or later. My answer states as much.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan: Yeah, I replaced with a path that exists, no variables, to prove the concept. For whatever reason I keep thinking in terms of PS V2, even though [there's V4 out there](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857339.aspx#BKMK_wps4).

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
$filenames = Get-ChildItem $to *.msi | Foreach Name
```

Or if on V2 or V1:

```
$filenames = Get-ChildItem $to *.msi | Foreach {$_.Name}
```

Comment: Thank you Keith for your answer

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe the results to [`Select-Object`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx):

```
$listOfMSIs = Get-ChildItem –Path $to -Filter "*.msi" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Of course, the above can be simplified to:

```
$listOfMSIs = Get-ChildItem $to *.msi | Select-Object -Expand Name
```